# How to place Ajax Load More button at the bottom of all posts?

Tags: css, ajax

[image]

On this screenshot, if you look in the North East corner, you'll find a 20% of the Ajax Load More button.

I have called it using the do_shortcode method in my template file right after I closed the loop to fetch the posts of this category.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>

                <?php
                endif;

                /* Start the Loop */
                $my_query = new WP_Query('cat=2,3&showposts=9');

                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile;
                the_posts_navigation();
            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

            endif; ?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="post" offset="9" images_loaded="true"]'); ?>
```

How would I go about placing it in a new line?

Live demonstration at -> http://www.technobyte.org/interesting-facts/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would mark something like that up. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/wcoyc0hf

I see that you are using PHP - but the same idea applies since PHP creates HTML.

"Put a border around it" - is the magic way to see that your floating and other styles are breaking the flow of things - and need to be addressed with clearfixes - in the case of floats / or generally just make sure things maintain their shape and that the parents of lists are expanding to hold them properly.

markup

```
<section class='stuff'>

  <ul class='thing-list'>
    <li class='thing'>
      <a href="#" class='image-wrapper link'>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="thumbnail">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class='thing'>
      <a href="#" class='image-wrapper link'>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="thumbnail">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class='thing'>
      <a href="#" class='image-wrapper link'>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="thumbnail">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class='get-more'>
    <button>more...</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

styles

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thing .link {
  display: block; /* link needs to be a block here to have shape */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.thing-list {
  overflow: hidden; /* should be a clearfix or use flexbox */
}

.thing-list .thing {
  float: left;
  max-width: 33%;
}

.get-more {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.get-more button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: So I added the border, and what actually is happening is that posts are getting loaded inside the same div element of the button. And the button should be pushed down below but I think because of the float left property, it is being pushed towards the right side

Comment: So, - now that you can see a bit more of what is happening - there are many ways to adjust your layout to address it. I've offered my loose approach in the example above.